# When to use aes mapping for the xend argument of the geom_segment() function in R's ggplot2 package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, aes

I'm trying to create 32 vertical line segments using the *mpg* column of the *mtcars* data frame. All is good when I run the following code:

```
a <- ggplot (mtcars) 
b <- geom_segment (x = 1:32, y = 0, aes (xend = 1:32, yend = mpg))
a + b
```

[image]

However, when I define the *xend* argument outside the *aes()* function, it looks like this.

```
a <- ggplot (mtcars) 
b <- geom_segment (x = 1:32, y = 0, xend = 1:32, aes (yend = mpg))
a + b
```

[image]

My question is, why doesn't it work? Why can I define *x* and *y* outside the *aes()* function but not *xend*? What does the new chart mean?

Answer (score 3):

So, to briefly recap, the purpose of the `aes()` function is to link up aesthetics with scales so they can be mapped. This is also why `colour = "blue"` will give a blue colour outside `aes()` but gets mapped to a discrete colourscale if you put it inside `aes()`.

Scales, amongst other things, measure the limits of the data range. If you define both `x` and `xend` outside the `aes()` and therefore these are not directly linked to a scale, the measurement that the scales are going to make won't see these values.

You can see in the example below that using that strategy gives you an x-scale that has default limits, instead of the limits as you would measure from the data.

```r
library(ggplot2)

a <- ggplot (mtcars) 
b <- geom_segment (x = 1:32, y = 0, xend = 1:32, aes (yend = mpg))
g <- a + b

sc <- layer_scales(g)
(sc$x$get_limits())
#> [1] 0 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you play around a bit more, you can see that you can define `geom_segment (aes(x = 1:32, yend =mpg), y = 0, xend = 1:32)`, which doesn't link the `xend` to a scale, but will display correctly anyway due to the scale seeing the `x` mapping.